# Search for term in array and return array entry containing that term

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am making a tool that analyzes words and tries to identify when they were most used.  I am using Google's Ngram datasets to do so.  In my code, I am streaming this data (which is about 2 gigabytes).  I am turning the stream data into an array, with each line of data as one entry.  What I want to do is to search for a certain word in the data, and store all the array entries containing the word in a variable.  I can find if the word is in the dataset, and print that word (or the position of it in the dataset) to the console.  I am still learning to program, so please keep that in mind if my code is messy.

```js
// imports fs (filesystem) package duh
const fs = require('fs');

// the data stream
const stream = fs.createReadStream("/Users/user/Desktop/authortest_nodejs/testdata/testdata - p");

// gonna use this to keep track of whether ive found the search term or not
let found = false;

// this is the term the program looks for in the data
var search = "proceeded";

// lovely beautiful unclean way of turning my search term into regular expression
var searchThing = `\\b${search}`
var searchRegExp = new RegExp(searchThing, "g");

// starts streaming the test data file
stream.on('data', function(data) {

  // if found is false (my search term isn''t found in this data chunk), set the found variable to true or false depending on whether it found anything
  if (!found) found = !!('' + data).match(searchRegExp);

  // turns raw data to a string and tries to find the location of the search term within it
  var dataLoc = data.toString().search(searchRegExp);

  var dataStr = data.toString().match(searchRegExp);

  // if the data search is null, continue streaming (gotta do this cuz if .match() turns up with no results it throws an error smh)
  if (!dataStr) return;

  // removes the null spots and line breaks, pretty up the displayed stuff
  var dataDisplay = dataStr.toString().replace("null", " ");
  var dataLocDisplay = dataLoc.toString().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

  // turns each line of raw data into array
  var dataArray = data.toString().split("\n");

  // log found instances of search term (dunno why the hell id wanna do that, should fix to something useful) edit: commented it out cuz its too annoying
  //console.log(dataDisplay);

  // log location of word in string (there, more useful now?)
  console.log(dataDisplay);
});

// what happens when the stream thing returns an error
stream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err, found);
});

// what happens when the stream thing finishes streaming
stream.on('close', function(err) {
  console.log(err, found, searchRegExp);
});
```

This currently outputs every instance of the search term in the data (basically one word repeated a hundred times or so), but I need an output of each entire line that contains the search term, not just the term.  ("Proceeded   2006    5   3", not just "proceeded")

Comment: Please update your question to show an example of your expected output and explain what result you're currently getting.

Comment: @Soviut all good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you're looking for something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function grep(path, word) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let
            stream = fs.createReadStream(path, {encoding: 'utf8'}),
            buf = '',
            out = [],
            search = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'i');

        function process(line) {
            if (search.test(line))
                out.push(line);
        }

        stream.on('data', (data) => {
            let lines = data.split('\n');
            lines[0] = buf + lines[0];
            buf = lines.pop();
            lines.forEach(process);
        });

        stream.on('end', () => {
            process(buf);
            resolve(out);
        });
    });
}

// works?
grep(__filename, 'stream').then(lines => console.log(lines))
```

I guess this is pretty straightforward, the `buf` stuff is needed to emulate line-by-line reading (you can also use `readline` or a dedicated module for the same).

Comment: Works well, but how do I remove the tabs?  I tried .replace('\t', ' ') on the output array, but they're still there.

Comment: @BearbaBear: `replace(string...)` only replaces once, you need a regexp: `.replace(/\t/g, ' ')`.